# Differences in wall/floor framing based on region.

Tags: wood, framing, construction

In the US, walls and decking/flooring tend to be framed with many long timbers and just a few cross braces/blocking pieces:

```
-------------------------------------------
|      |      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |      |
|------|      |------|      |------|      |
|      |------|      |------|      |------|
|      |      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |      |
|      |      |      |      |      |      |
-------------------------------------------
```

I've been watching "Grand Designs New Zealand" which is a show about modern house building in the region and I've noticed a lot of the framing there looks more like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
|         |         |         |         |   
|         |         |         |         |   
|         |         |         |         |   
|---------|---------|---------|---------|   
|         |         |         |         |   
|         |         |         |         |   
|         |         |         |         |   
|---------|---------|---------|---------| 
|         |         |         |         |   
|         |         |         |         |   
|         |         |         |         |   
|---------|---------|---------|---------|    
|         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         |
|         |         |         |         | 
-----------------------------------------
```

It appears they allow the primary structural members to have a much larger gap between each one, but they use a whole lot more cross-blocking.

Just curious if that is a general difference in terms of those two regions and, if so, what are the arguments for doing the latter?